# How do I show all perspectives in my rcp project eclipse perspective bar (coolbar) upon startup?

Tags: eclipse, rcp, perspective

Upon startup I only have the Open Perspective button and the default perspective that I set in method `getInitialWindowPerspectiveId` on its right. I want to show all my other perspectives on that coolbar.

Until now i tried:

- config.ini file with `org.eclipse.ui/PERSPECTIVE_BAR_EXTRAS=id1,id2,id3`
- plugin_customization.ini with `org.eclipse.ui/PERSPECTIVE_BAR_EXTRAS=id1,id2,id3`
- in class `ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor` in the initialize method someone said to do this:

  PlatformUI.getPreferenceStore().setDefault(IWorkbenchPreferenceConstants.PERSPECTIVE_BAR_EXTRAS,"id1,id2,id3");
  PlatformUI.getPreferenceStore().setValue(IWorkbenchPreferenceConstants.PERSPECTIVE_BAR_EXTRAS,"id1,id2,id3");

Nothing worked.
However i found a workaround:
in class `ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor` in the `postWindowOpen` i manually show all my perspectives. This leaves them opened in the coolbar. However this is not the optimum way and maybe someone knows the proper way to show all my perspective shortcuts on the coolbar.

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().showPerspective("id1", getWindowConfigurer().getWindow());
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().showPerspective("id2", getWindowConfigurer().getWindow());
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().showPerspective("id3", getWindowConfigurer().getWindow());
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The 'plugin_customization.ini' method should work

- The 'plugin_customization.ini' file must be in your RCP plugin
- The 'plugin_customization.ini' must be included in the build in the 'build.properties' file.

Comment: It is included in the build ofcourse. I also make sure to clear the workspace and config area before re-running the project, still doesn't work. I must be missing something...